Efficiently Split a Large CSV File into Smaller Files by Index Range Without Loading Entire File into RAM
I have a big CSV file (60GB) that does not fit into RAM. The first column contains a sorted index that goes from 2000 to 2999 and can be repeated between rows. I want to split the 60GB file into 10 files of approximately 6 GB each, but without "splitting" the index between two of the files.
Thus, the first one will have rows with index 2000 to 2099, the next one with items from 2100 to 2199, etc. The files should also keep the header of the first file.
I can't use a tool like qsv's split, because the number of rows might be different in each of the 10 files. I also tried using qsv apply, but it seems to try to load everything into the RAM.
Update: Miller also looks promising. I don't know If I should use split or tee, as I don't want to add an extra column to my table.

To your question add the answers to the following: 1) What are you planning to do with the data? 2) Why does where the index splits matter?  Also, have you looked at Polars, in particular it's Lazy API and Streaming.

I plan to distribute the data. The split does matter in case someone wants to analyze just a subset or wants to merge other similar dataframes with the same index. About using these kinds of libraries, I'm trying to avoid it because I don't really want to "parse" the csv into numpy/python objects.

I ended up writing a 150 lines C program. It assumes that the index is in the first column, and that the filename has the format [0-9]+to[0-9]+_.*, like 10000to10999_Blocks.csv.
It stores just the current line and the previous one, and compares them to check how the index has changed.
The output files will be written to the current directory.
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <stdio.h>
#include <string.h>
#include <errno.h>

// Use wc --max-line-length to discover max line length
// It returned 296
#define MAX_LINE_LENGTH 512
#define MAX_DIGITS_LENGTH 16
#define swap(x,y) do \
   { unsigned char swap_temp[sizeof(x) == sizeof(y) ? (signed)sizeof(x) : -1]; \
     memcpy(swap_temp,&y,sizeof(x)); \
     memcpy(&y,&x,       sizeof(x)); \
     memcpy(&x,swap_temp,sizeof(x)); \
    } while(0)
#define DAVO_CHECKPTR(n) __davo_checkfile(n, __FILE__, __LINE__)

void __davo_checkfile(const void * ptr, const char f[], const int l) {
    if (ptr == NULL) {
        fprintf(stderr, "Error: %s (%d)\n", strerror(errno), errno);
        fprintf(stderr, "@ %s:%d\n", f, l);
        exit(1);
    }
}

void parse_fname(const char * fname, char* from, char* to, char *rest) {
    // Parse filename in the format XXXXXtoYYYYY_ZZZZZZ
    enum fsname_fname_parser {
        FIRST_NUMBER,
        TO_2,
        SECOND_NUMBER,
        REST,
    } state = FIRST_NUMBER;
    int j = 0;

    for (int i = 0; fname[i] != '\0' && i < 1024; i++) {
        // printf("state: %d, fname[%d]=%c, from[%d]=%c, to[%d]=%c\n", state, i, fname[i], j)
        switch (state) {
            case FIRST_NUMBER:
                if (fname[i] == 't') {
                    state = TO_2;
                    from[j] = '\0';
                } else {
                    from[j] = fname[i];
                }
                j++;
                break;
            case SECOND_NUMBER:
                if (fname[i] == '_') {
                    state = REST;
                    to[j] = '\0';
                    j = 0;
                } else {
                    to[j] = fname[i];
                    j++;
                }
                break;
            case TO_2:
                state = SECOND_NUMBER;
                j = 0;
                break;
            case REST:
                rest[j] = fname[i];
                j++;
                break;
        }
    }
    rest[j] = '\0';
}

int common_prefix_length(const char *str1, const char *str2, const int max_n) {
    int i = 0;
    while (str1[i] == str2[i] && i < max_n) i++;
    return i;
}

int line_to_fname(const char *line, char *fname, int extra_digits, const char * rest) {
    char from[MAX_DIGITS_LENGTH];
    char to[MAX_DIGITS_LENGTH];
    int i;

    for (i = 0; line[i] != ','; i++) {
        from[i] = to[i] = line[i];
    }

    from[i] = to[i] = '\0';
    for (int j = i - extra_digits; j < i; j++) {
        to[j] = '9';
    }

    sprintf(fname, "%sto%s_%s", from, to, rest);
}

int main(int argc, char* argv[]) {
    FILE * fi = NULL, *fo = NULL;
    int required_cpl, extra_digits, index, lastindex = -1;
    char header[MAX_LINE_LENGTH];
    char auxbuf1[MAX_LINE_LENGTH] = "\0";
    char auxbuf2[MAX_LINE_LENGTH] = "\0";
    char * line = auxbuf1, * lastline = auxbuf2;
    char from[MAX_DIGITS_LENGTH], to[MAX_DIGITS_LENGTH], rest[MAX_LINE_LENGTH];

    if (argc < 2) {
        fprintf(stderr, "Usage: %s filename [extra_digits=1]\n", argv[0]);
        return EXIT_FAILURE;
    }

    parse_fname(argv[1], from, to, rest);
    extra_digits = (argc==3)?atoi(argv[2]):1;
    required_cpl = extra_digits + common_prefix_length(from, to, MAX_DIGITS_LENGTH);
    printf("from: %s, to: %s, rest: %s, cpl: %d, rcpl: %d\n", from, to, rest, common_prefix_length(from, to, MAX_DIGITS_LENGTH), required_cpl);

    DAVO_CHECKPTR(fi = fopen(argv[1], "r"));
    // Save header to variable
    DAVO_CHECKPTR(fgets(header, MAX_LINE_LENGTH, fi));

    printf("Saved header: %s", header);

    while (fgets(line, MAX_LINE_LENGTH, fi) != NULL) {
        // If first line or should split
        if (lastline[0] == '\0' || (lastline[0] != '\0' && common_prefix_length(line, lastline, required_cpl) < required_cpl)) {
            char output_fname[MAX_LINE_LENGTH];

            if (fo != NULL) fclose(fo);

            // Open new file and write header
            line_to_fname(line, output_fname, extra_digits, rest);
            printf("Split to %s\n", output_fname);
            DAVO_CHECKPTR(fo = fopen(output_fname, "w"));
            // Write header
            fputs(header, fo);
        }

        fputs(line, fo);

        swap(line, lastline);
    }

    fclose(fi);
    fclose(fo);
}


How fast did this run?

I see you have your own answer, but I wanted to give this a try.
I've read your question many times, and think your input looks something like:
Idx,  X
2000, 1
2000, 2
2001, 3
2099, 4
2100, 1
2198, 2
2200, 1
2301, 1

and given that simple input, I think that you would want something like:
2000_to_2099.csv    2100_to_2198.csv   2200_to_2200.csv  2301_to_2301.csv
----------------    ----------------   ----------------  ----------------
Idx,  X             Idx,  X            Idx,  X           Idx,  X
2000, 1             2100, 1            2200, 1           2301, 1
2000, 2             2198, 2
2001, 3
2099, 4

I tried running your program, but could not figure out how to make it work against that intput.  The only way I could get multiple files is if the first digit was different, like:
Idx,  X
2000, 1
3000, 1

Then I'd get two files, 2000to2009 and 3000to3009, with the correct splits (I also kept getting an invalid char error when final name was made, so I removed the "rest" part of the name).
So I don't really know what your input looks like, and I don' really t know what you expect...
Still, I like efficiency problems, and especially comparing solutions, so I created the same program in C, Go, and Python that will produce those splits given that simple input I made up.  They're all highly optimized based on your description of the range of indexes, 2000-2999, and they don't bother tracking the last index in a block of 100, because you only seem to want that for the filename, and that can be figured out by a simple shell script with tail, and it makes the code simpler and smaller.  Also, I don't really know C: I cribbed from your answer, and got some clarifying help from ChatGPT.
C:
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <string.h>

typedef char Index[5];
typedef char Line[512];

int main(int argc, char* argv[]) {
  FILE *fi = NULL, *fo = NULL;
  Index idx = "0000\0";
  Index first = "\0\0\0\0\0";  // init with nulls for first[0]!=0 "empty-first" check
  Line header = "";
  Line line = "";
  char nameBuf[9] = "\0";  // 2000.csv
  char* fname = nameBuf;

  fi = fopen(argv[1], "r");
  fgets(header, 512, fi);

  fo = fopen("2000.csv", "w");
  fputs(header, fo);

  while (fgets(line, 512, fi) != NULL) {
    memcpy(idx, line, 4);
    if (idx[1] != first[1]) {
      if (first[0] != 0) fclose(fo);

      sprintf(fname, "%s.csv", idx);
      fo = fopen(fname, "w");
      fputs(header, fo);

      memcpy(first, idx, 4);
    }
    fputs(line, fo);
  }
  fclose(fo);

  return 0;
}

Go:
package main

import (
    "bufio"
    "fmt"
    "os"
)

func main() {
    fi, _ := os.Open(os.Args[1])
    scanner := bufio.NewScanner(fi)

    scanner.Scan()
    line := scanner.Bytes()
    header := make([]byte, len(line))
    copy(header, line)

    var (
        idx   = make([]byte, 4)
        first = make([]byte, 4) // initialize with four 0's, for first[0]!=0 "empty-first" check

        w  *bufio.Writer
        fo *os.File

        write  = func(data []byte) { w.Write(data); w.WriteByte('\n') }
        openf  = func(fname string) { fo, _ = os.Create(fname); w = bufio.NewWriter(fo); write(header) }
        closef = func() { w.Flush(); fo.Close() }
    )

    openf("2000.csv")
    for scanner.Scan() {
        line = scanner.Bytes()
        copy(idx, line[:4])
        if idx[1] != first[1] {
            if first[0] != 0 {
                closef()
            }
            openf(fmt.Sprintf("%s.csv", idx))
            copy(first, idx)
        }
        write(line)
    }
    closef()
}

Python:
import sys

EMPTY = b"____"

with open(sys.argv[1], "rb") as fi:
    first, idx = EMPTY, EMPTY

    header = next(fi)

    fo = open("2000.csv", "wb")
    fo.write(header)

    for line in fi:
        idx = line[:4]
        if idx[1] != first[1]:
            if first != EMPTY:
                fo.close()

            fo = open(f"{idx.decode()}.csv", "wb")  # decode bytes b"2000" to string "2000" (as utf-8)
            fo.write(header)

            first = idx

        fo.write(line)

    fo.close()

Finally, I made this shell script to look at the split CSVs and figure out the first and last indexes with head and tail commands:
#!/bin/sh
set -e

ls 2*.csv | while read csv; do
    first=$(head -n2 "$csv" | tail -n1 | cut -d, -f1)  # read header and first row, then just the row
    last=$(tail -n1 "$csv" | cut -d, -f1)
    mv "$csv" "${first}_to_${last}.csv"
done

Running that script after splitting the sample input from above produces the named files from above with the corresponding contents.
To test, I created a generator script in Python that makes, as best as I understand, your input, based on a SIZE var to scale the number of rows:
import random

SIZE = 87

f = open(f"input-big-{SIZE:>03}.csv", "w")
f.write("Idx,  X\n")

for base_idx in [2000, 2100, 2200, 2300, 2400, 2500, 2600, 2700, 2800, 2900]:
    n = 1
    for i in range(100):
        for j in range(1, random.randint(54 * SIZE, 60 * SIZE)):
            f.write(f"{base_idx+i}, {hex(n)}\n")
            n += 1

With SIZE=87 I get a file of about 60MB:
Idx,  X
2000, 1
2000, 2
2000, 3
...
2099, 493699
2099, 493700
2099, 493701
2100, 1
2100, 2
2100, 3
...
2199, 494338
2199, 494339
2199, 494340
...
2999, 570864
2999, 570865
2999, 570866

I ran each program/script against that big input 4 times, and captured the real component from the built-in time command: for the compiled programs the first runs looks like a cold start, and the subsequent three runs go faster:
c:      0.543s 0.347s 0.345s 0.307s
go:     0.444s 0.200s 0.192s 0.195s
python: 1.080s 1.083s 1.032s 1.065s

I'd expect on my machine, an M1 Macbook Air with dual-channel SSD, that running on the real file would take about 6m for the C program and 2m30s for the Go program.  I also take that the Go program runs faster than the C program to mean that I haven't optimized something in C (bigger buffer?).  Here's the sys timings, with the C program usually spending more time with sys calls:
c:      0.093s 0.150s 0.209s 0.068s
go:     0.102s 0.083s 0.083s 0.083s

